# How to reload a component (" <Comment />) in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angularjs

I was working on react project. I was trying to reload a component (`<Comment />`) when we click the Post Comment button. I implemented the onSubmit function as given below. But it is reloading the whole window. I just want to reload only that "" Component, not the whole window. Can anyone help me to solve this?
I don't understand what to do,  please help .....!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import ImageHelper from "../helper/ImageHelper";
import { getoneBlog, postBlogComment } from "../helper/coreapicalls";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { isAutheticated } from "../../auth/helper/index";
import cogoToast from "cogo-toast";
import "../../styles.css";
import Comment from "./Comment";
import ShareButton from "react-web-share-button";

const Fullblog = (config) => {
  const useremail = isAutheticated() && isAutheticated().user.email;
  const blogId = useParams();
  const id = blogId._Id;
  // console.log(id);
  const history = useHistory();

  const [blog, setBlog] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    tags: "",
    photo: "",
    comment: "",
    loading: false,
    error: "",
    createdBlog: "",
    getaRedirect: false,
  });
  const [value, setvalue] = useState({
    user: useremail,
    content: "",
    err: "",
    success: false,
  });
  const [error, seterror] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { user, content, err, success } = value;

  const onInputChange = (name) => (event) => {
    setvalue({ ...value, err: false, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setvalue({ ...value, err: false });
    postBlogComment(id, { user, content })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.error) {
          setvalue({ ...value, err: data.error, success: false });
        } else {
          setvalue({
            ...value,
            user: useremail,
            content: "",
            err: "",
            success: true,
          });
         
        }
      })
      .catch(console.log("Error in sending Comment"));
  };

  const loadBlog = () => {
    getoneBlog(id).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        seterror(data.error);
      } else {
        setBlog(data);
        // console.log(data);
      }
    });
    setLoading(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadBlog();
  }, []);
  ///////////////////////////// Post Submit Event ///////////////////

  const successMessage = () => {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <div className="">
          <div
            className="alert alert-success"
            style={{ display: success ? "" : "none" }}
          >
            Comment Posted..!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const errorMessage = () => {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <div className="">
          <div
            className="alert alert-danger"
            style={{ display: err ? "" : "none" }}
          >
            {err}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="py-md-5 py-3">
        <div className="Fullblog container">
          <div>
            <h1 className="FullblogTittle">{blog.title}</h1>
            <p className="tags text-right">{blog.tags}</p>
            {loading ? (
              <ImageHelper blog={blog} />
            ) : (
              <div class="spinner-border text-danger" role="status"></div>
            )}
            <div
              className="description"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: blog.description }}
            />
            <span>
              <ShareButton
                buttonStyle={{
                  color: "#ffca08",
                  background: "#fff",
                  padding: "10px 12px",
                  border: "none",
                  width: "100%",
                }}
              />
            </span>
            <div className="container Comment_stytum mt-4">
              {successMessage()}
              {errorMessage()}
              <div className="mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                <div className="">
                  <textarea
                    className="comment_input"
                    name="content"
                    value={content}
                    onChange={onInputChange("content")}
                    placeholder="Write Comment"
                  ></textarea>
                </div>
                <input
                  className="d-none"
                  name="user"
                  value={user}
                  onChange={onInputChange("user")}
                />
                <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit} className="post-btn">
                  Post Comment
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Comment />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Fullblog;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you test with this modification?

```
<form className="mx-sm-3 mb-2" onSubmot={onSubmit}>
  <div className="">
    <textarea
      className="comment_input"
      name="content"
      value={content}
      onChange={onInputChange("content")}
      placeholder="Write Comment"
    ></textarea>
  </div>
  <input
    className="d-none"
    name="user"
    value={user}
    onChange={onInputChange("user")}
  />
  <button type="submit" className="post-btn">
    Post Comment
  </button>
</form>
```

Cause using `button type='submit'` is about to submitting a form (but there is none) and usually, with `submit`, we declare the method on the `form`.

Comment: not working :(  I think My post Comment Button and <Comment /> has no relation between

Comment: thanks, please with this question stackoverflow.com/q/66156615/15160538 @farvilain

Answer (score 0):

to rerender a component you should update his state or props, in your case, I will suggest that you try to find the relation between the two components like you send the comment data as props and after you add a new comment you update the state and the comment component get the data as props from the state, so it will rerender automatically, otherwise, you can use forceUpdate() but I don't recommend that

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: can You please tell me how can I make a relation between  Post Comment and <Comment />, my Comment component  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- >

Comment: import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getBlogComments } from "../helper/coreapicalls";
import user_img from "../../image/user.png";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import "../../styles.css";

Comment: const Comment = () => {
  const blogId = useParams();
  const id = blogId._Id;
  // console.log(id);

  const [showComment, setShowComment] = useState([]);
  const [error, seterror] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadComments();
  }, []);

Comment: const loadComments = () => {
    getBlogComments(id).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        seterror(data.error);
      } else {
        setShowComment(data.comment);
        // console.log(data.comment);
      }
    });
    setLoading(true);
  };

Comment: return (<div><div className="Comment_systum container">{showComment.map((comment, index) => { return (<div className="card mt-2" key={index}><div className="card-header user_email"><imgsrc={user_img}alt="User"className="img-fluid Fullblog_comment_img" /> {comment.user}</div><div className="card-body"><blockquote className="blockquote mb-0"><p>{comment.content}</p><footer className="blockquote-footer text-right">Time<cite title="Source Title ml-2 text-right">{comment.createdAt}</cite></footer></blockquote></div></div>);})}</div></div>);};

Comment: I suggest that you refactor your comment component and make it without data inside, so you load the data in the parent component and you update the parent state with the data  then you pass it to comment like that <Comment showComment={showComment} />